# How does jQuery.each() work with associative arrays (objects)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, associative-array

I have an associative array with two object inside. Running this through `$(myassoc).each()`, the callback runs only once. Also the callback parameters (index and object) returns 0 and the entire associative array, respectively.

One would expect `jQuery.each()` to run for each element in the array, returning the correct keys as index and the correct element as the object.

Why isn't that happening, and can jQuery do what I'm after?

Comment: can you please show the code? `$(obj).each()` works fine with

Comment: Have you tried `$.each(myassoc, func...`?

Comment: If you have only two objects inside (2 keys of array) so there will be only two iterations. If you want to `each` those two objects you have to do `.each` again for them

Comment: JavaScript _HAS NO_ associative array

Comment: @Raynos Associative array is just another word for a key/value mapping as far as I know. I did specify "objects" in the title.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you're looking for [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead of .each()

try this:

```
    $.each(myassoc, function(index, value){
      //your code
    });
```

Comment: just avoid `length : 0`  inside your object and you good to go

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
$.each(assocarray,function(i, value){
  console.log('index: ' + i + ',value: ' + value);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

## Badly.

Don't `$(associative_array).each(function () {...})` -- that's [nonsense](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#working-with-plain-objects)

Don't `$.each(associative_array, function() {...});` -- that has an obscure [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3588#issuecomment-288682581)<sup>(1)</sup>

To see the bug, try this in a javascript console:

```
> $.each({foo:1, length:-1, bar:2}, console.log)
  foo 1
  length -1
  bar 2
> $.each({foo:1, length:0, bar:2}, console.log)
```

The first example outputs three lines of key-value pairs, as it should. The second outputs nothing!

The moral of the story, **don't use jQuery.each() on objects**. (Objects in JavaScript are [essentially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067675/673991) the [same thing](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html) as associative arrays.) Things may work fine forever, but you run the risk that someday an object happens to have a member named `length` and its value happens to be exactly `0` and then you have a bug out of nowhere that can be very difficult to explain. (I'll let you guess, by the ponderous heft of this answer, whether that ever happened to me.)

As mentioned in the [bug report](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3588#issuecomment-288682581):

> If you need to iterate over all keys of objects having the length property, jQuery.each is not the correct solution.

I suggest going further, that jQuery.each should not be relied upon for associative arrays, ever.

<sub>(1) This "bug" may never be fixed, since $.each() historically uses [Duck Typing](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on arrays: "Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index."</sub>

---

Here's what I use<sup>[thanks [Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735184/673991)]</sup> to **loop through property names and values** of objects, or put another way, the keys and values of an associative array:

```
function looper(object, callback) {
    for (var key in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (false === callback.call(object[key], key, object[key])) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return object;
}
```

looper() is then a drop-in replacement for $.each()

```
> looper({foo:1, length:0, bar:2}, console.log)
  foo 1
  length 0
  bar 2
```

[Just like $.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#entry-longdesc):

- Inside the callback, `this` is each value
- Inside the callback, returning `false` (not just falsy) terminates the loop
- looper() returns the object originally passed to it
- looper() works on arrays as well as objects.

---

Use:

```
var a = [];
looper({foo:1, length:0, bar:2}, function(k, v) { 
    a.push(k+"="+v); 
});
console.assert("foo=1,length=0,bar=2" === a.join());
```

Try that with $.each() and you'll get an empty result. Because it interprets this particular object as an array-like object of zero length.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `$.each()` function internally retrieves and uses the `length` property of the passed collection. But in an associative array *that has no integer indices* the `length` always seems to be `0`. For `$.each()` now there seems to be nothing to walk through.

> The [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function internally retrieves and uses the `length`
>   property of the passed collection.

The solutions is simply to use an object instead.

```
var obj = {
  "flammable": "inflammable",
  "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```