# Is declaring an associative array as a new Array() the same as declaring an associative array as an object {}?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is the object `whiteStripes` the same exact thing in both cases?

```
var whiteStripes = {'Jack' : 'White', 'Meg' : 'White'};

var whiteStripes = new Array();
whiteStripes['Jack'] = 'White';
whiteStripes['Meg'] = 'White';
```

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript

Comment: `var whiteStripes = new Object();` would be the same thing, but not with `new Array()`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067590/associative-array-versus-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you will still be able to access the properties the same way (`whiteStripes['Jack']`) in both instances when you declare `whiteStripes = new Array();` you are saying it has all the properties and attributes of an array like `length` for example.  If you are not intending to use it as a true array (`pop`, `push`, `length`, etc.) then don't use a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not the exact same thing.

Both will work, because an array is *also* an object, but if you want just an object you should not create an array to get one.

These would result in the exact same thing being created:

```
var whiteStripes = {'Jack' : 'White', 'Meg' : 'White'};

var whiteStripes = new Object();
whiteStripes['Jack'] = 'White';
whiteStripes['Meg'] = 'White';
```