# JS Array Values as Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in javascript and I want to use its values as keys for another array.

```
var arrKeys = ['place', 'name', 'age' ];
var result = [place]['name']['age'] = 5;
```

Now I want to check if there is a value for this keys in another associative array:

```
if ( result[place][name][age] {
   console.log('exists');
}
```

How can I use the values from arrayKeys as array keys in the result array?

Comment: `result[arrKeys[0]][arrKeys[1]][arrKeys[2]]` maybe?

Comment: Use objects instead of arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067590/associative-array-versus-object-in-javascript

Comment: Hey Ronny, there is so much wrong with this code. var result = ~~~ = ~~~~. That is never a way to go in JS

Comment: @Nicky **do not change code**, especially in questions. Post new answer if you want that explain "here is your typo" and how to fix it.

Comment: Aha. ok, fair enough. in this part (var result = [place]['name']['age'] = 5;). You have three indexes: place,'name','age'. The first one is a variable, the second and third are constant. This can not be the intention, and if it is, you have to provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

Really easy:

```
var result = new Array();

var arrKeys = ['place', 'name', 'age' ];
result[arrKeys['place']][arrKeys['name']][arrKeys['age']] = 5;
```

However. This might still give you some errors. So i would do it like this, just to be save.

```
var arrKeys = ['place', 'name', 'age' ];
var result = new Array();
result[arrKeys['place']] = new Array();
result[arrKeys['place']][arrKeys['name']] = new Array();
result[arrKeys['place']][arrKeys['name']][arrKeys['age']] = 5;
```

As you can probably see, this is the way to set the variable you want. You can acces the variable again with:

```
result[arrKeys['place']][arrKeys['name']][arrKeys['age']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for (i=0;i<arrKeys.length;i++) {
  if (typeof(result[arrKeys[i]])!="undefined") {
    console.log('exists');
  }
}
```

Could this work for you?