# How to get the correct array length

Tags: javascript

In my code i initialize array then put a value inside it why the output be 0 ?in spite of this should be 1

```
       var changedfields=[];
       changedfields['product']="productname";
       alert(changedfields.length);
```

Comment: You are confusing objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an associative array (normal arrays have an numeric index) but are actually trying to build a HashMap (a key, value pair). Use Objects or [ES6 Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

I hope the following example will help you out:

```
var changedfields = {}; // create an object
changedfields['product']="productname";
var keys = Object.keys(changedfields);  // returns the keys of the object ['product']
alert(keys.length);
```

I would suggest to read more about datastructures in javascript and avoid associative arrays in general.

- [Length of a JavaScript object (that is, associative array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array?rq=1)
- [associative array versus object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067590/associative-array-versus-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is interesting. Following is the answer.

**First of all Arrays in Javascript are object type.**

The first line you wrote creates an empty array and it's type is object.

```
var changedfields=[];
```

The second line you wrote creates a property called *product* of *changedfields* and sets the value to *productname*. It allows you add the *product* property because Javascript Array type is object. If you just had *var changedfields;* you could not add this property.

```
changedfields['product']="productname";
```

The third line you wrote simply finds the length of the empty array.

```
alert(changedfields.length);
```

In Javascript associative arrays are achieved using object. But if you want to add the product name in *changedfields* array. You could use push method like below and check the length:

```
changedfields.push('productname');
console.log(changedfields.length);
```

**Javascript numerical indexed array length**
So the Javascript numerical indexed array length can be calculated this way:

```
console.log(array.length);
console.log(changedfields.length); // in your case
```

**The Javascript associative array length**
The Javascript associative array (object) length can be calculated following ways:
**Option 1:**

```
Object.len = function(obj) {
var objLen = 0;
for (i in obj) {
   obj.hasOwnProperty(i) ? objLen++ : '';
}
return objLen;
};
console.log(Object.len(changedfields));
```

**Option 2:**

```
console.log(Object.keys(array).length);
console.log(Object.keys(changedfields).length); // in your case
```

Note: This has issues with Internet Explorer 8, Opera etc