# JavaScript "Associative" Object vs. Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

at the moment I am using an object to simulate an associatve array.
The object acts like a one to many relationship table from mysql
For Example:

```
var obj = {
  105: [],
  200: []
  //...
}
```

My property names are only numeric so I found out that I could use an array, too.
But then the empty entries between the indices are filled with `undefined`.

```
var arr = [];
arr[10] = "Value";
arr[15] = "Value 2";
//arr => [undefined*10, "Value", undefined*4, "Value 2"]
```

So when I am going to iterate over that array I have to check if the value at the current index is set.

So the question is, which of the solutions is faster or better.
Using an object or an array where
the empty space between the indizes is filled with `undefined` values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8067678/3166303

Comment: In your case object should possibly use less memory. Iterating both structures is mostly the same, however you have to remember that object properties in JavaScript don't have order.

Comment: [See this link for your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a key-value association, you need an object.
If you want an *ordered list* in which the keys don't really matter, an array it is.

FYI, the indices "between" set indices in an array are not actually "filled" with `undefined`; you merely get the `undefined` value when you try to access a non-existing property on any object:

```
({}).foo; // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking which is "faster or better". For "better" many possible answers exist, but "faster" has a clearer answer: as others pointed out there is hardly any speed difference between `Object` and `Array`. Both have the same roots in the prototype hierarchy. An `Array`'s empty values are not "filled".

**Regarding your use case the bottleneck will not be the object, but how you loop it!** This actually *does* make a difference: `for` loops are faster than any other way of looping. But you have the problem of the non-continuos numeric indices.

Therefore: just benchmark how long it takes if you do

- `for(key in object)`
- `keys = Object.keys()` and `for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)`

as these two should be your fastest options.