# Function doesn't work and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have this function that I wish to spit out some object information if there is something in it. But I am stuck. Anyone know what the problem is?

```
function ifExist(property) {
    if ( randomObj.property === "" ) {
        message += "";
    } else {
        message += "<span class='propString'>" + randomObj.property + "</p>";
    }
    return message;
}

ifExist(citation);
ifExist(year);
```

Thanks in forehand!

Comment: you have to use a string as well as the indexer.

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket notation for referencing changing keys: `randomObj[property]`  That should allow you to use dynamic property name to pull values from keys on your object.

Using `randomObj.property` (dot notation) will literally find the key named `property` on your `randomObject`.

In addition, make sure to pass your keys in as strings:

```
ifExist("citation");
ifExist("year");
```

As mentioned by Ovér Flôwz, it's also a smart idea to make sure that key exists on your object before trying to process any data that you can't guarantee exists.

Comment: Would me telling you that I am working with an array object make any difference..??

Comment: Can you give me an example of this array? If you're using arrays vs. key/value objects, you'll have to make some minor changes in how you look up the desired value. Related link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067590/associative-array-versus-object-in-javascript

Comment: var people = [
{ name: "John",
lastname: "Hancock" },
{ name: "Peter",
lastname: "Parker" }
 ];

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
function ifExists(obj, property) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(property);
}

var obj = { myprop: 'I got this.' };
console.log(ifExists(obj, 'myprop')); // also notice quotes.
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine what are you checking: whether the property does not exist at all on certain object or it equals `null` or empty  (`""`) or `undefined` or `false` or `0` depending on its type.

In first case use `object.hasOwnProperty(property)`.
For all other cases (when you know the property exists):

```
if (!object[property]){
    //...
}
```

Better not to use single quotes inside tag attributes. The right way is:

```
var message += '<span class="propString">';
```

or you can escape it:

```
var message += "<span class=\"propString\">";
```