# key of a JavaScript object must be a string

Tags: javascript, object

In JavaScript, if you type

```
typeof("2")
```

you should get `string`.

And if you type

```
typeof(2)
```

you should get `number`.

Now my question is, it is said that when you define an object, the key must be a string.

so this is legal

```
apple = {"color":"red"}
```

However, if I change the key to a number wrapped in the inverted commas, it should work as anything inside of inverted commas

```
apple={"2": "red"}
```

But If I call the object property, `apple.2`, this will fail with error `Unexpected number`.

so am just curious, what am I missing here while defining the objects in JavaScript.

Comment: FYI `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so the parentheses are unnecessary. The object's key must be a string, so you'd need to access it via `apple["2"]`, not using a number via `apple.2`.

Comment: Dot notation is restricted to valid JS identifiers, `2` is not a valid JS identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object key must be a string, but JavaScript allows you to assign an object with a number. It's just converted to a string behind the scenes, so:

```
apple = {2: "red"}
```

is the same as:

```
apple = {"2": "red"}
```

Using dot notation requires a valid identifier. So you can not access the property with `apple.2` as 2 is a number, instead, you have to use bracket notation, either `apple["2"]` or `apple[2]`.

Incidentally, there are other cases which can not be accessed with dot notation, such as:

```
apple = {"hyphenated-key": true}
```

Trying to access `apple.hyphenated-key` would not work, you have to use bracket notation as such `apple["hyphenated-key"]`.

Comment: and after some research, we can't do ```foo.bar.baz``` for an object which is defined like ```foo={bar.baz : value}```. I think objects as associative arrays make more sense in most of the little complicated-shaped objects.  If anyone wants to unnderstand better, follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067590/associative-array-versus-object-in-javascript)